# Multiple S3 events together trigger a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have a scenario where I have two buckets s3-a and s3-b.
When data is put into s3-a it sends out an S3 event.
The same happens with s3-b.
I need to trigger a lambda function when I have the data in both the S3 buckets.

One way I could think of is use a dynamodb as a marker if a corresponding S3 object is found, then through dynamodb streams invoke a lambda which checks if both the markers are true.

Comment: Why do you keep posting the same question, slightly differently each time, instead of updating your original question?

Comment: This is a bit different one Mark, though it looks similar to the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Check the data in both buckets in each trigger. Whichever trigger finds data in both buckets, proceeds further. Make it Idempotent so that if both triggers find the data in both buckets, there is no adverse effect.

Comment: Should I be thinking of to use a ddb to ensure that they are idempotent

Comment: that is up to you how you implement it.